# Matching two arrays with exact number of unique values VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, intersection

I have searched Google as well as the Stack for examples of what I am trying to accomplish below, and while there are some good examples out there that are similar; I am having a little trouble getting my code to work the way I need it to

In the table below we have a table with user input (with animal values) and a corresponding Group ID. What I am trying to do is find the unique values in the group ID column and cross check them with different arrays. The code I have now checks to see which arrays share the same unique values.

However, as you can probably tell from the image I have included, the code that I have finds ALL arrays that have unique values in common. This would include arrays where said unique values are a subset of a larger array. What I am trying to do is find the array with the exact same unique values, nothing more nothing less; and when there is a match; a certain sub is executed.

Tables and Arrays are shown below:
[image]

so the logic behind it would be as follows:

```
if array3 = arrayMain _ 'the array in the main table (orange 
then 
array3Query 'run sub linked to array 3
...
if array4 = arrayMain then
array4Query 'run query linke to array 4
...
if array5 = arrayMain then
array5query 'etc..
...
```

Below is the function I currently have:

```
Function UniqueVal(ByRef Arr1, ByRef Arr2)

    If TypeOf Arr1 Is Range Then Arr1 = Arr1.Value2
    If TypeOf Arr2 Is Range Then Arr2 = Arr2.Value2

    Dim e, x, i As Long

    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        .CompareMode = 1
        For Each e In Arr1
            If Len(e) Then .Item(e) = Empty
        Next
        For Each e In Arr2
            If .Exists(e) Then .Item(e) = 1
        Next
        x = Array(.Keys, .Items)
        .RemoveAll
        For i = 0 To UBound(x(0))
            If x(1)(i) = 1 Then .Item(x(0)(i)) = Empty
        Next
        If .Count Then UniqueVal = .Keys
    End With

End Function
```

Which in turn is called by the below procedure:

```
Sub iTestIntersection()

MsgBox Join(UniqueVal(Worksheets("arrayTest").Range("B2:B6"), Worksheets("arrayTest").Range("D2:D5")), vbLf)
MsgBox Join(UniqueVal(Worksheets("arrayTest").Range("B2:B6"), Worksheets("arrayTest").Range("F2:F7")), vbLf)
MsgBox Join(UniqueVal(Worksheets("arrayTest").Range("B2:B6"), Worksheets("arrayTest").Range("F10:F13")), vbLf)
MsgBox Join(UniqueVal(Worksheets("arrayTest").Range("B2:B6"), Worksheets("arrayTest").Range("D10:D12")), vbLf)
    ''''''

End Sub
```

Any suggestions on what I would need to add to the above function and or procedure to accomplish what I am attempting to do (minus the message box of course; just trying to run the sub linked to it :)

Answer (score 0):

If `Arr1` isn't an array, but only a single value it will pass that value into `ArrTemp(0)` then `ReDim Arr1(0)` turning it into an empty array and finally it passes the original value back into `Arr1(0)`. There might be an easier/better way to do this, but I think this will work for you. (I set the dictionary up with a name so I could debug easier.)

```
Function UniqueVal(ByRef Arr1, ByRef Arr2)

    Dim ArrTemp(0)
    Dim e, x, i As Long
    Dim xDictionary As Object

    If TypeOf Arr1 Is Range Then Arr1 = Arr1.Value2
    If TypeOf Arr2 Is Range Then Arr2 = Arr2.Value2

    If TypeName(Arr1) <> "Variant()" Then
        ArrTemp(0) = Arr1
        ReDim Arr1(0)
        Arr1(0) = ArrTemp(0)
    End If

    Set xDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With xDictionary
        .CompareMode = 1

        For Each e In Arr1
            If Len(e) Then .Item(e) = Empty
        Next

        For Each e In Arr2
            If .Exists(e) Then
                .Item(e) = 1
            Else
                .RemoveAll
                UniqueVal = .Keys
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next

        x = Array(.Keys, .Items)
        .RemoveAll
        For i = 0 To UBound(x(0))
            If x(1)(i) = 1 Then
                .Item(x(0)(i)) = Empty
            Else
                .RemoveAll
                UniqueVal = .Keys
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
        If .Count Then UniqueVal = .Keys
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! However, it seems like the above still finds matches when at least 2/3 values are shared where the original array is larger. For instance, if the group ID array is {7, 6, 3}; it will identify {7, 6} as a positive match. Tried playing around with it to see if I could figure out why, haven't had success yet

Comment: Thanks! That edit worked. For some reason however, when the first array has only one value (and by extension the second array would be only a single cell range, ie .Range("F11"), .Range("F11:F11")), a type mismatch error is returned. I also tried using .Range("F11:F12") where F12 is empty, but then it doesn't return a match for some reason o.O

Comment: @Singularity20XX did this get everything sorted for you? If so, mind marking this as answered?